# Function store() and update()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to adapt my store function () for my update () method, I think the problem is in my condition ?

In my function store() I have this: (ok)

```
   $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
   $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
   $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
   $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
   $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');


    $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
    ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) 
    ->first();  

    $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->first();



    $conflictFormer = Training::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
    ->first();  

    $conflictMotorbike = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
    ->first();  


    if(isset($conflictTraining) || isset($conflictRevision) || isset($conflictFormer) || isset($conflictMotorbike) ){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
             ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
    }

    else{
        Training::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'Add');
}
```

In my function update() i have this:

```
    $date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
   $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
   $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
   $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
   $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');


    $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
    ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) 
    ->first();  

    $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->first();



    $conflictFormer = Training::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
    ->first();  

    $conflictMotorbike = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  

    ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
    ->first();  


    if( (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id))
    ||  (isset($conflictRevision) && $conflictRevision->id !== intval($id)) 
    ||  (isset($conflictFormer) && $conflictFormer->id !== intval($id)) 
    ||  (isset($conflictMotorbike) && $conflictMotorbike->id !== intval($id)) ){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('error', 'Duplicate! ');



    else{
        $trainings = Training::find($id);
        $trainings->date_start = $request->get('date_seance');
        $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
        $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
        $trainings->fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
        $trainings->fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
        $trainings->save();
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'update')->withInput();
    }
}

}
```

I think the problem is here??? My condition is doesn't correct ??

```
if( (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id))

    ||  (isset($conflictRevision) && $conflictRevision->id !== intval($id)) 
    ||  (isset($conflictFormer) && $conflictFormer->id !== intval($id)) 
    ||  (isset($conflictMotorbike) && $conflictMotorbike->id !== intval($id)) ){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('error', 'Duplicate! ');
```

if you have any ideas do not hesitate...

Thank you for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is in the conditional.  Or at least part of the problem.

The `$id` that you are checking against, which is coming in from your form, is only good for one thing: the **Training** model.  So, checking to see if the `id` is a match to the conflicted models (**Revision**, **Motorbike**, **Former**), will either fail or be incorrect.  (The `id` for the training shouldn't match to any of the above models).  The only reason to check against that `id` is to make sure that your duplicate training isn't the same one that is coming in from the form - IE if it is the same, it should be allowed to be edited, and not flagged as a duplicate.  The other checks are to see if there is a legitimate duplicate.

To fix this, remove the check for `id` match on everything but the **Training** model.  Something like this (just doing this manually, you'll need to double check the code).

**Conditional**:

```
if( (isset($conflictTraining) && $conflictTraining->id !== intval($id))
  ||  isset($conflictRevision) 
  ||  isset($conflictFormer)
  ||  isset($conflictMotorbike) // <-- Don't need this or its query per edit
){
      return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
             ->with('error', 'Duplicate! ');
```

All of this said, this method is getting pretty beefy / complex.  You may wish to consider limiting some of this or maybe taking some of the heavy lifting into another method or area.  Once you get this up and running, you may also want to trim down some of that code to make it more efficient.

**Queries**

Also - the query on `$conflictFormer` has an issue.  The `fk_former` check is in the query twice.  Hmm, looks like several of your queries have multiple `where` statements on the FK that can be removed.

Looking a little closer, some of that 'beefiness' is getting complicated.  By running your training query like this:

```
$conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
  ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  
  ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
  ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
  ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))  // <-- only if same former
  ->where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) // <-- repeated code
  ->first();
```

This is not checking if ANY training is conflicting, but rather if a training is conflicting with a specific former.  I would remove the last two `where` statements here.  You check for the conflicted former later.

The last query for `$conflictMotorbike` is unnecessary, as the first query for conflicted training already tells you this because you checked for that motorbike in the initial part of the query.  Suggest you remove that and the `isset` check for `$conflictMotorbike`.

Comment: Ah, it works Watercayman, thanks ... ^^ You're right, some lines can be deleted ... I'm going to focus on this problem. Once again a big thank you for your explanations.